# Multiselection in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here's my issue : I need to build a C# application with WPF where the users can select numerous lines from a DataGrid. But, despite the fact I put the selection mode to "Extended" I'm only able to select a single row from the GUI.

I thought I could circumvent this problem by programmatically select the row the user clicks, but again I can only select one row at time ! I searched a lot on the internet but didn't find a simple way to select multiple rows in a datagrid

I'm a beginner with WPF and I'm not very good with DataBinding and MVVM pattern, so if the the answers could be simple it'd be perfect !

Thank's a lot !

Comment: In fact, I want that a single click on a row has the same effect than control+click, like in a listbox. If it's not possible, I'll test the checkbox method.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the checkboxes method, referring to this article : http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/11/26/multiselect-datagrid-with-checkboxes.html

It works great and it's really easy to implement. At least the part with the checkbox. I put the CanUserResizeRows property to false, which resolved the issue with the gripper !

Answer (score 0):

Changing the selection mode and selection unit should most probably fix your problem. It's working in my case.
In you XAML, set you following DataGrid attributes:

```
SelectionUnit="FullRow"
SelectionMode="Extended"
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can Add Template column for CHECKBOXES for selection.
refer this [Multi-select ASP.NET datagrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4973/Multi-select-ASP-NET-datagrid) to get complete solution.

Comment: The question is about WPF, not ASP.NET

Answer (score -1):

By default, you need hold shift and click to select multipe rows, really make no sense. Most people chose the check box approach. But wpf don't give you a simple option.

Comment: Can you provide details / example ?

Comment: @ironman, I vote T2o's answer. Try it and you will find it's not that difficult.